# Run Pipeline sequentially on circle CI for cypress

Tags: cypress, circleci

I have a cypress e2e test running on Circle ci and I need to set it up to run the Chrome browser first and then Firefox(only after Chrome finished all the test runs). Here I have listed the yml file and any suggestions. appreciated.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.29.0
executors:
  with-chrome:
    docker:
      - image: 'cypress/browsers:latest'
  with-firefox:
    docker:
      - image: 'cypress/browsers:latest'
  with-electron:
    docker:
      - image: 'browsers/cypress-electron:latest'

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:

  - cypress/install:
      install-command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-engines

  - cypress/run:
      name: Chrome
      yarn: true
      requires:
        - cypress/install
      executor: with-chrome
      browser: chrome
      post-steps:
        - run: ls
        - store_test_results:
            path: results
        - store_artifacts:
            path: cypress/screenshots

  - cypress/run:
      name: Firefox
      yarn: true
      requires:
        - cypress/install
      executor: with-firefox
      browser: firefox
      post-steps:
        - run: ls
        - store_test_results:
            path: results
        - store_artifacts:
            path: cypress/screenshots
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run jobs sequentially with CircleCi, you can use `requires`.

```
  - cypress/install:
      install-command: yarn install --frozen-lockfile --ignore-engines

  - cypress-chrome:
      name: Chrome

  - cypress-firefox:
      name: Firefox
      requires:
         - cypress-chrome
```

More details on https://circleci.com/docs/workflows/

Comment: @ Wandrille thank you for comment, I Have added missing code actualy there were executors mentioned and i updated my question, I have tired your  mentioned but it failing under : _Job 'Firefox' requires 'cypress-Chrome', which is the name of 0 other jobs in workflow 'build'_ :  many thanks if you have anything to share on this

Comment: You can replace then cypress-chrome by just 'Chrome", it would work I imagine

Comment: wow it justed worked perfectly, thank you for prompt reply, cheeers!!